# Open and close a shape with the same "button"

Tags: excel, macros

i have an arrow and when i click on it a cloud shape should appear. This works fine now. What i want now is that if i click the same button again the cloud should disappear. I gues i need to make my cloud an object and as for its state or something but i didnt figure out how yet.. this is my code:

Sub bubble()

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCloudCallout, 795, 8.25, 107.25, 41.25). _
        Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = -0.25029
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "text..."
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10). _
        ParagraphFormat
        .FirstLineIndent = 0
        .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    Range("P5").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

<strike>Dim shp As String</strike>

```
Sub Bubble()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCloudCallout, 795, 8.25, 107.25, 41.25). _
        Select

    shp = Selection.Name
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = -0.25029
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "text.................."
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10). _
        ParagraphFormat
        .FirstLineIndent = 0
        .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    Range("P5").Select
End Sub

Sub FlipFlop()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(shp)
        .Visible = Not .Visible
    End With
End Sub
```

We **create** the *callout* with a slight mod to your `Bubble()` code.  We assign the `FlipFlop()` code to your arrow Shape.

Each time you click on the arrow, the *callout* will toggle between visible and not visible.

**EDIT#1:**

I found

```
the problem.  Remove the old code and use:

Sub Bubble2()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCloudCallout, 795, 8.25, 107.25, 41.25). _
        Select

    Selection.Name = "zooky"
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = -0.25029
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "text.................."
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10). _
        ParagraphFormat
        .FirstLineIndent = 0
        .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    Range("P5").Select
End Sub

Sub FlipFlop2()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("zooky")
        .Visible = Not .Visible
    End With
End Sub
```

instead.

Comment: if i do this my sheet gets empty :D

Comment: @z  repeat this on a clean sheet.

Comment: @zooky  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: gives me an error here: With ActiveSheet.Shapes("zooky") <- the element with this name could not be found.  (kinda strange since you named it zooky in the second row.. right?)